# Very high cpu load, but usage is low

Tags: cpu

I have been seeing a very high cpu usage on my Raspbery Pi:
load average: 97.69, 97.60, 97.21

However, I have been closely monitoring `htop` for a while and cpu usage is around 30-40%. Looks like the culprit is `jbd2` when it writes.

Is there a way to see which processes are causing this?

Comment: load average is not only about CPU load. It could be I/O load. Is your RAM full and the swap space being used? (you can type `free` in the terminal to check)

Comment: It looks like the problem is jbd2 constantly writing. Is there a way to check what process is causing this.

Comment: Check for processes marked as D.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the output of `top` will list pids and show the 90+ that are not sleeping. Likely they are all waiting on IO if your CPU is not maxed out.